# Javascript define string constants as shorthand properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there any way to define a string value like a shorthand property, something like e.g. (this doesn't work):

```
const dict = {
    USER_LOGIN,
    USER_LOGOUT
};
```

Which will be equivalent to:

```
const dict = {
    USER_LOGIN: "USER_LOGIN",
    USER_LOGOUT: "USER_LOGOUT"
};
```

I want to define a constants dictionary, but I was wondering if I can somehow avoid the repetition pattern `MYVALUE : "MYVALUE"`.

Is there any shorthand way of declaring object keys with values equivalent to their string values, similar to the (not working) code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shorthand property notation will only work when you have a variable having the same name as the property you want to declare:

```js
const USER_LOGIN = 'USER_LOGIN';
const USER_LOGOUT = 'USER_LOGOUT';

const dict = {
    USER_LOGIN,
    USER_LOGOUT
};

console.log(dict);
```

Otherwise, you have to specify the whole object:

```
const dict = {
    USER_LOGIN: "USER_LOGIN",
    USER_LOGOUT: "USER_LOGOUT"
};
```

Or create it via a helper as @CertainPerformance mentionned.

Answer (score 3):

There's no built-in way to do something like that automatically, but if you want to keep the code DRY, you can make a helper function that, when passed an array of strings, creates an object with those properties:

```js
const makeDict = arr => arr.reduce((a, str) => ({ ...a, [str]: str }), {});
const dict = makeDict(['USER_LOGIN', 'USER_LOGOUT']);
console.log(dict);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just kidding:

```js
let dict;

with(new Proxy({}, {
  get(_, key) { return key; },
  has(_, key) { return key !== "dict"; }
})) {
  dict = {
    USER_LOGIN,
    USER_LOGOUT
  };
}

console.log(dict);
```

If you think *that does not work...* just try it :)

But seriously: The whole question is just overkill.

Comment: Yeah, it might be an overkill, I was just trying to be sure that there's no convenient notation that I might be missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare them and use those constants as `key-value` on an object.

```js
const USER_LOGIN = "USER_LOGIN";
const USER_LOGOUT = "USER_LOGOUT";  

const dict = { USER_LOGIN, USER_LOGOUT };

console.log(dict);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```